# Android 5.0 Lollipop - Redirect the traffic of a specific app through a VPN with proxy

Tags: android, proxy, vpn

How can I setup the next situation in Android 5.0?

1. All network communication of app A should be made through an VPN connection with a proxy;
2. The other apps should continue to communicate directly through the wireless connection, without any proxy.

I was partly able to do this in Android 4.4 KitKat. I configured the VPN, turned it on and configured the proxy ip and port in the wireless network details. Android started to redirect the traffic of all apps through VPN and proxy.

When I do the same in Android 5.0, the results are worst! The apps simply continue to use the wireless connection directly, without any consideration of the VPN and proxy.